# ReactJS table with material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the material UI minimized table to create a dashboard https://material-ui.com/pt/components/tables/

I ran into an issue that I'm stuck with for the last 5 hours. I could successfully render the data from my database to display in the table. However, when I retrieve the data using the map function, all is displayed in one single row x5.

Picture: [Front-end view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tTZS.png)

I'm trying to display the name and data in different rows and not "Sue  Flavio  John    Doe rajid" because each is a different object.

I'd appreciate some help to understand where is my logical mistake.

```
function EmployeeList() {
  const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState([]);

  console.log(employeeList);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/vacations_cs_read").then((response) => {
      setEmployeeList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const Row = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useRowStyles();

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TableRow className={classes.root}>
          <TableCell>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="expand row"
              size="small"
              onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
            >
              {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {employeeList.map((val, key) => {
              return <td>{val.employeeName}</td>;
            })}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left">
            {employeeList.map((val, key) => {
              const day = new Date(val.employeeStartDay).toLocaleDateString(
                "pt-BR"
              );
              return <td>{day}</td>;
            })}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left">
            <p>-</p>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left">
            <p>-</p>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left">
            <p>-</p>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <Box margin={1}>
                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                  History
                </Typography>
                <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>From</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>To</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">Days</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">Paid</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <TableBody>
                    {/* {row.history.map(() => (
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row"></TableCell>
                        <TableCell></TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))} */}
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>
              </Box>
            </Collapse>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  Row.propTypes = {
    row: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string,
      startDate: PropTypes.string,
      shift: PropTypes.string,
      daysReceived: PropTypes.number,
      daysUsed: PropTypes.number,
      daysLeft: PropTypes.number,
      history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          amount: PropTypes.number,
          customerId: PropTypes.string,
          date: PropTypes.string,
        })
      ),
    }),
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell />
              <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Employment Date</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Days received</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Days used</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Days left</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {employeeList.map((val, key) => (
              <Row />
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are not giving the data to each row in the `map` call where you iterate over the employees. And then, instead you iterate of the whole thing again in each cell..

This should work:

```
const Row = ({val}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const classes = useRowStyles();
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableRow className={classes.root}>
        <TableCell>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="expand row"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {val.employeeName}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">
          {(new Date(val.employeeStartDay)).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">
          <p>-</p>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">
          <p>-</p>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">
          <p>-</p>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <Box margin={1}>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                History
              </Typography>
              <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>From</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>To</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">Days</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">Paid</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {/* {row.history.map(() => (
                      <TableRow>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row"></TableCell>
                      <TableCell></TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))} */}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </Box>
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

Row.propTypes = {
  row: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    startDate: PropTypes.string,
    shift: PropTypes.string,
    daysReceived: PropTypes.number,
    daysUsed: PropTypes.number,
    daysLeft: PropTypes.number,
    history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        amount: PropTypes.number,
        customerId: PropTypes.string,
        date: PropTypes.string,
      })
    ),
  }),
};

return (
  <div>
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Employment Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Days received</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Days used</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Days left</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {employeeList.map((val, key) => <Row val={val} key={key}/>)}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Just missed one thing to the code actually works. At the function Row(), should be used the destructuring of the val.

const Row = (val) => {
    const { row } = val

I appreciate the attention and patience to help.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've updated the answer with the fix to the issue you found.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you should be using should look something like this:

```
function Row(props) {
   // you can access the employee object as `props.employee`
   ...
}

...

{employeeList.map((val, key) => <Row key={key} employee={val} />}
```

Each time you call the row function, it gives you a new row. For it to know what data should be in that row, you should be passing that data as a prop, instead of using the state. The flow of data would therefore be that the render method has a list of employees, and it calls the row builder function once with each of them, which gives back a list of rows to render.